# How to get object whose return type is the List interface in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, interface

I am using an open-source code, and one of their API returns `List<String>` whereas `List` is an `interface`. I know that they designed it this way to make the API more general, but how do I use this? I just want to get the result. If I try something like:

```
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) ...
```

I get an `ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList` error.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to perform that cannot be done on an object of type List?

Answer (score 1):

Why not work with the interface?

```
List list = (..your method call..)
```

If the list returned by the API is a different implementation of the `List` interface (i.e. not `ArrayList`), you can't cast it to `ArrayList`. You can construct a new `ArrayList` and initialize it with the `List` you get from the API, but I don't see the point.

The API you are using is returning some implementation of the `List` interface. You don't need to care which implementation they are currently using. That's the point of using interfaces - they can change the implementation tomorrow, but since the API returns the `List` interface type, any code that uses that API won't have to change.

Comment: Isn't List an interface that can't be used without an implementation?

Comment: @pandagrammer The API you are using is returning some implementation of the List interface. You don't need to care which implementation they are using. That's the point of using interfaces - they can change the implementation tomorrow, but since the API return the interface type, any code that uses the API won't have to change.

Answer (score 0):

If your api returns list then you could do the following and get all the operations of list like:

```
List list = myobject.mymethod();
```

And then irrespective of list implementation like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` etc., you could still do add/remove/iterate/etc. over the list as you already have reference to ArrayList from what returns from the mymethod.